# Kubernetes and vSphere, AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, linux-containers, kubernetes

I am a bit late to the party and am just delving into containers now. At work we use vSphere as our virtualization platform, but are *likely* to move to "the cloud" (AWS, GCP, Heroku, etc.) at some point in the somewhat-near future.

Ideally, I'd like to build up our app containers such that I could easily port them from running on vSPhere nodes to AWS EC2 instances.

So I ask:

- Are all Docker containers created equal? Could I port a Docker container of our own creation to [AWS Container Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) with zero config?
- I *believe* [Kubernetes](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/kubernetes) helps map containers to the virtualization resources they need. Any chance this runs on AWS as well, or does AWS-ECS take care of this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes is designed to run on multiple cloud platforms (as well as bare metal). See [Getting started on AWS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/aws.md) for AWS specific instructions.